# MD5 Public-Private Key Encryption (python)

Tags: encryption, cryptography, python-cryptography

I've trying to encrypt my data using asymmetric encryption. I've chosen MD5 as the algorithm. PS: I know about MD5 collisions.

I'm following [this blog](https://nitratine.net/blog/post/asymmetric-encryption-and-decryption-in-python/) to encrypt and decrypt my data. This uses SHA256. I'm able to run the code successfully with SHA1, SHA512 as well, but not with MD5.

Whenever, I change the algorithm to MD5, it says

```
cryptography.exceptions.UnsupportedAlgorithm: This combination of padding and hash algorithm is not supported by this backend.
```

**Which padding should be used to encrypt the data with MD5?**

My Code:-

```
# ########## Encrypting and decrypting ##########
message = b'encrypt me!'
encrypted = public_key.encrypt(
    message,
    padding.OAEP(
        mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.MD5()),
        algorithm=hashes.MD5(),
        label=None
    )
)
original_message = private_key.decrypt(
    encrypted,
    padding.OAEP(
        mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.MD5()),
        algorithm=hashes.MD5(),
        label=None
    )
)
```

Comment: Usually there is only a specific set of paddings supported   (such as pkcs1.5, oaep+mgf1-sha-1, oaep+mgf1-sha256).  I am not sure for this specific library. The encryption is RSA, the hash is used for the mask (oaep) generation. So you should not say "encrypt with MD5".

Answer (score 0):

Actually, MD5 is (an old) hash algorithm, it is not an encryption algorithm. A hash is used to get a sort of "checksum" for a given text (or data byte array). That "checksum" as a fix length, whatever is the size of the text you hash.

In cryptography, you typically may use hash function to get a private (symmetric) key from a passphrase or you may encrypt a hash with a private key : this is a digital signature.

Comment: Similar is the case with SHA family.

Comment: You're right. So my answer won't help, sorry. Actually the padding...() is used to add a signature at the end of the encrypted message...  if you only want your message to be encrypted but not signed (for signature is not allowed with md5) I guess you can ignore it.